# Getting common values in a table based on a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, relational-division

I couldn't find what I am looking for even though it seems like a 'simple' thing to do in SQL.

So here it is,

- I have a table containing dates and countries, let's call it A.
- I have a subquery that selects a list of countries from a table C, let's call it B.

The goal is to return only and distinctively the dates from A that have every single country in B

For example,

```
A                              B (SELECT FROM C WHERE ...)
date         country           country
2020-07-21   1                 1
2020-07-21   2                 2
2020-07-12   1
2020-07-12   2
2020-07-06   1
2020-07-06   2
2020-07-06   3
```

Should return

```
date
2020-07-21
2020-07-12
2020-07-06
```

But if B was

```
B
country
1
2
3
```

then it should return

```
2020-07-06
```

The whole point is to get all the dates that have all the country listed in the B list

I tried

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT T.date FROM (
    SELECT date
    FROM A
    WHERE country = ALL (SELECT country FROM C WHERE ...)
) AS T
```

But it doesn't return anything because I think it only returns the list if it is true for everything.

Here is an MCRE:

```sql
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_date` date NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `projects_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

INSERT INTO countries VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO countries VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO countries VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO projects(project_date, country_id) VALUES ('2020-07-21', 1);
INSERT INTO projects(project_date, country_id) VALUES ('2020-07-21', 2);
INSERT INTO projects(project_date, country_id) VALUES ('2020-07-12', 1)
INSERT INTO projects(project_date, country_id) VALUES ('2020-07-12', 2)
INSERT INTO projects(project_date, country_id) VALUES ('2020-07-06', 1);
INSERT INTO projects(project_date, country_id) VALUES ('2020-07-06', 2);
INSERT INTO projects(project_date, country_id) VALUES ('2020-07-06', 3);
```

Then this is what I try to do

```sql
SELECT project_id, project_date
from projects
where country_id = all (select country_id from countries where country_id in (1,2))
group by project_date
```

I know the subquery is useless here but in reality, the condition is different from `IN (1,2)` but this simplifies it without losing the meaning of what I'm trying to do.

In this database, with (1,2) in the subquery, it should return every date as they all have the country_id 1 and 2. However, if it was set to (1,2,3) it should only return '2020-07-06' as a group because it is the only date with the country_id 1,2 and 3

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: You are jumping to (wrong) conclusions. Also there is no "clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal", ie question, in this post. Read the post. Please act on the comments.

Comment: Excuse me, but I have never been good at phrasing anything, unfortunately. Here I'll try to explain and if you want you can try to find a better phrasing for it. I have a list of date linked to countries, (usually, there will be the same date in multiple countries, but not always), and what I am trying to do is, based on a variable list of countries, get all the dates that are linked to ALL the countries in the list (a date must be linked to every countries in the list in order to be taken into account)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your query that returns the countries from `C` is something like:

```
select country_id from countries where country_id in (....)
```

then use it like this:

```
select project_date
from projects
where country_id in (select country_id from countries where country_id in (...))
group by project_date
having count(*) = (select count(*) from countries where country_id in (...))
```

If there are duplicate countries in `projects` then change the `HAVING` clause to:

```
having count(distinct country_id) = (select count(*) from countries where country_id in (...))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=26bae0c3f215031c21fab761ecb9e701).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below way -

```
select date
from tablename 
group by date
having count(distinct country)=(select count(distinct country) from countryTable)
```

Comment: I see what this is doing but the issue is that I cannot rely on counting the countries because there are actually more than 2 countries and I would like to be able to differentiate  1,2 from 2,3 for example.